# Django Ajax POST request fail to redirect

Tags: jquery, django, ajax, redirect

I am trying to create a website to capture picture from client's camera and save it in the database. However after everything was saved, I cant seem to redirect the page.

views.py

```
def facial_capture(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.FILES['snap']
        if file:
            student = Student.objects.get(id=request.session['id'])
            if student:
                FaceImage.objects.create(student=student, image=file)
                return HttpResponse("{'status': 1}", content_type='application/json')
        return HttpResponse("{'status': 0}", content_type='application/json')
    return render(request, 'id_capture/facial_capture.html')
```

face_capture.html

```
{% block body %}
    <div class="container">
        <form>{% csrf_token %}
            <video id="video" width="640" height="480" autoplay></video>
            <button id="send">Submit</button>
            <canvas id="image_canvas" width="640" height="480"></canvas>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

face_capture.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var video = document.getElementById('video');
    var canvas = document.getElementById('image_canvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var w = 640, h = 480;

    if(navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true }).then(stream => {
            video.srcObject = stream;
            video.play();
        });
    }

    document.getElementById("send").addEventListener("click", function() {
        context.translate(w, 0);
        context.scale(-1, 1);
        context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, w, h);
        canvas.toBlob(upload, "image/jpeg");
    });

    function upload(file) {
        var formData =  new FormData();
        formData.append("snap", file);
        const csrftoken = document.querySelector('[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').value;

        $.ajax({
            headers: {'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken},
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/signup/facial_capture',
            data: formData,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
            success: function(data){
                console.log('response received');
                if (data.status == 1) {
                    console.log('status ok');
                    window.location.href = "login";
                } else {
                    console.log('status failed');
                    window.location.reload();
                }
            }
        })
    }
});
```

I assume that after the return HttpResponse it will get to the function in ajax success and redirect to login page but somehow I am still at the facial_capture page with csrfmiddlewaretoken attached.

My question is that is this the right way to redirect the page after successfully send post request with ajax or am I doing anything wrong?

**Edit:**
url.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('login', views.login, name='login'),
    path('signup/facial_capture', views.facial_capture, name='facial_capture')
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Your code should work. You need to debug the `data` value to ensure you're getting back what you expect, and also check the console. The first thing I would suggest is that `{'status': 1}` is not valid JSON - `{"status":1}` is - check the quotes. As an aside, note that generating your own hard-coded JSON formatted string is not good practice. Create an object/class in your server side code and serialise it before sending it in the response.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I changed the status as you and user8133129 said. I also tried to log it out in the console first without redirecting or reloading but there's nothing

Answer (score 1):

```
//  Your django code should be like this

return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'status': "1"}), content_type="application/json")
```

And in the Django template, you should assign the url as follows.
{% url 'login' %}

```
function upload(file) {
        var formData =  new FormData();
        formData.append("snap", file);
        formData.append('csrfmiddlewaretoken', '{{ csrf_token }}');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "{% url 'facial_capture' %}",
            data: formData,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
            success: function(data){
                console.log('response received');
                if (data.status == 1) {
                    console.log('status ok');
                    window.location.href = "{% url 'login' %}";
                } else {
                    console.log('status failed');
                    window.location.reload();
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: I tried to change url to '{% url 'facial_capture' %}' and "{% url 'facial_capture' %}" and '{% url "facial_capture" %}'. The first on show Uncaught SyntaxError: missing } after property list in the console and the last 2 show Not Found: /signup/{% url "facial_capture" %} in the terminal.

Comment: Please show me your urls.py, In the django template, you should specify the name of the URL not actual url
example 
path('facial_capture/', views.facialCapture, name="facial_capture_url"),

In ajax use url name not url 
"{% url 'facial_capture_url' %}",

Comment: I put it in the edit above. Please let me know if there is anything wrong

Answer (score 0):

First of all, instead of a HttpResponse you could use a JsonResponse that takes in a dictionary.
Secondly, window.location.href takes either an absolute url or a relative url starting with a /

Comment: I changed to window.location.href = '/login' but nothing happened. I also tried to alert the data first without redirecting or reloading and it's still the same

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to figure out why. I forgot to declare button type, and by default it is a submit button. All I need to do is to change the button to:

```
<button id="send" type="button">Submit</button>
```

And also, by everyone suggestion, I should change the response to:

```
return JsonResponse({"status": 1})
// or
return HttpResponse(json.dumps({"status": 1}), content_type='application/json')
```